# Bottle sub-template render issue

Tags: html, python-2.7, web, bottle

I am having real difficulty getting to grips with bottle sub-templates. 
Ideally what I want to do is grab a value from an HTML form, that asks the user to specify a number of items. Then a sub-template will be rendered which creates a form based upon the number of items selected. But I am stuck getting any sub template to work at all. The example from the bottle docs is this:

```
% include('header.tpl', title='Page Title')
Page Content
% include('foother.tpl')
```

So I have a .tpl file called hello which looks like this:

```
<h1>Hello World </h1>
% include('goodbye.tpl')
```

And a .tpl file called goodby that looks like this this:

```
<h1> Goodbye World </h1>
```

And a script that looks like this:

import bottle as bt
import webbrowser as wb

```
@bt.route('/sub_template', method = 'GET')
def test():
    return bt.template('hello')

def main():     
    wb.open('http://localhost:8080/sub_template')
    bt.run(host = 'localhost', port = 8080, debug = True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

But I receive:

```
NameError: name '_base' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I seem to be using version 0.11. Is this a version issue?

Answer (score 0):

Happy to delete this if needs be, but it seems that the system was changed between version 0.11, and 0.12. Having updated the package it seems to be fine.

Comment: Happy you solved the problem.  FWIW, I switched from Bottle's built-in templating to Jinja2 and found Jinja2 to be more flexible and powerful yet just as simple.

Comment: Yes, I'm rather regretting my choice at present, if anything just because the bottle community is so small, and the docs are so sparse. However, bottle works with Pythonista as it is 'pure python'. Im not sure that is the case with jinja2

Comment: AFAIK, jinja2 is pure python.